# How format email body in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, html-email

I want to send email using my grails application. It is working fine but what i need is i want to format the email body with bold  , italics , bullet lists , text colors etc. I tried using html markup like

```
      <strong> Hello </strong>
```

for bold

```
 <br>
```

for line brake etc. But the received mail content shows the html code itself. How i can solve this? Thanks in advance.

```
sendMail {
                async true
                to toAddress
                subject "New cycle initiated"
                body "<p><span style='color:#ffffe0'><strong><span style='background-color:#ff0000'>Appraisal Initiated mail notification. This is a test mail</span></strong></span></p>"
                }
```

this is my code

Comment: Include the code you are using to send the e-mail in your question.

Comment: @joshua the code is included

Comment: i'm receiving the same html code in mail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send mail as HTML using the Grails mail plugin, you need to use the `html` parameter instead of `body`.

```
sendMail {
    async true
    to toAddress
    subject "New cycle initiated"
    html "<p><span style='color:#ffffe0'><strong><span style='background-color:#ff0000'>Appraisal Initiated mail notification. This is a test mail</span></strong></span></p>"
}
```

Comment: Thank you doelleri.. Its working.. and one more thing.. How can i split this html code into multi line?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by multiline. You can place it in a template and use `html g.render(template: 'template.gsp')`. I strongly recommend you look at the [Grails mail plugin docs](http://grails.org/plugin/mail).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single GSP file and call it in sendMail as below.

File in 'grails-app/components/mail.gsp'

```
sendMail { async true
           to toAddress
           subject "blablabla"
           body(view:"/components/mail", model:[data:data])}
```